# Passing arguments to callback in scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I want to pass some arguments to the callback() when using
 `minimize(obj, x, args=(args, ), method='L-BFGS-B', callback=callback)`
Here, (args,) is the arguments passed to obj. My question is how to pass args to callback?
Thanks for the help.

Edit:
I want to call the callback as callback(xk,args). As mentioned in the comment, the callback itself is only called with callback(xk), where xk is the current x-vector. 
My current solution is to define a global variable to store args. My callback will read and modify this global variable. A pseudo-code is as

```
args = 0
def callback(xk):
    global args
    args = args + 1
    ...
```

I would like to know if there is a more professional way to pass it.

Comment: Maybe you want to outline what you are trying to do. Then one could reason about approaches (like hacky function-attributes). The callback itself is only called with ```callback(xk)```, where ```xk``` is the current x-vector.

Comment: Are you hoping that changing `args` in the callback will change the `args` that get passed to your `obj` function?  That could be tricky.  Your change would have to modify mutable objects.  The `callback` is intended more as a way of monitoring the current value of `x`, and possibly performing some sort of 'stop-action'.

Comment: @hpaulj I use callback for monitoring inversion, saving iterates and apply projection type regularization to the iterates. For saving iterates, I want to pass the file names to callback. The regularization part is tricky. Usually, I need objective function, changing regularization parameter according to the iteration number for the callback.